# Add Entity Framework Model to Class Library

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have created a class library and added a EF Model but as soon as I declare a variable my project just skip the rest of my code without any error. I do not understand what is causing this to happen.

Library Code

```
public class Phisc
{
    //Global DB Entity variable
    live_restoreEntities db = new live_restoreEntities();

    //Write data to file
    public void PhiscFile(int value)
    {
        string strFileName, strFilePath;
        StreamWriter stm;

        //Create a file name that will be created
        strFileName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + "_PHISC";
        //The path that were the file will be saved
        strFilePath = "c:\\" + strFileName + ".txt";

        //Validate if file exists
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(strFilePath))
            System.IO.File.Create(strFilePath).Dispose();

        stm = new StreamWriter(strFilePath, false);

        stm.Write("This is a test message from C#");

        stm.Close();
    }
}
```

WinForm Code

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Phisc.Phisc pFile = new Phisc.Phisc();
    pFile.PhiscFile(14);
}
```

When I create a instance of the library it does not hit my PhiscFile Method.

I have added a breakpoint to it and it stops at this constructor

```
public live_restoreEntities() : base("name=live_restoreEntities", "live_restoreEntities")
{
    this.ContextOptions.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    OnContextCreated();
}
```

I am using a windows application to test my library

Comment: Please edit your question and post the code surrounding ´live_restoreEntities db = new live_restoreEntities();´.

Comment: And what exactly is the problem now? What code gets skipped?

Comment: All of my code get skipped. It hits my declaration and then it just skip all my code.

Comment: WHAT code gets skipped? Where is it?

Comment: Your `Phisc` class resides in a namespace which is also called `Phisc`, right?

Comment: Do you have reference to `EntityFramework.dll` in your winforms project? If not, try adding it and test again.

Comment: @ThomasWeller yes that is correct

Comment: @Mathew I do have a reference to EntityFramework.dll

Comment: Do you have the app.config in your WinForms project?

Comment: And by skip, do you mean that without any error, form load completes and you get the form displayed without hitting your method?

Comment: @JensKloster No I do not have since the WinForm is only for testing purposes. I only call the method to the library

Comment: Then the problem should be something along the lines of the answer by Jens Kloster.

Comment: @Mathew that is correct

Comment: @G-Man *not* having an app.config in your WinForms project is what causing your error - please se my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameterless constructor goes out and look for the conenctionstring in the App.config file. It look next to the .exe file.

I'm guessing that you need to include your App.config (from your entity library) to your WinForms library.

In the App.config, it should look like this:

```
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="live_restoreEntities" 
         connectionString="<your connection string here>"
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: If this was the case, then the c'tor of the db context would throw an exception.

Comment: @ThomasWeller yes you are right. I believe that OP's is just not been shown the exception.. perhaps some IDE configuration could reviel it.

Comment: You should see it in the debugger anyway, right? Also, in case of an exception, the breakpoint inside the c'tor wouldn't be hit.

Comment: @ThomasWeller if the breakpoint is at the decalring line of the constructor, then it *will* "hit" that breakpoint, before continuening to the `base("...")` where I belive the exception is thrown.